# Unable to make a list of http get calls through one service in angularjs to handle exceptions?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, http

**Process:**
I try to call 4 httpget call though one httpGet method in a service, my first httpget call return an error and the rest of the calls return success message.

**issues:** I try to call that error function response to my controller but through console error ***TypeError:errorFunction is not a function***

[image]

**Code:**

**myController:**

```
app.controller('myCtrl',["myService",function(myService){
     var id =10;
     $scope.getTemp = function () {
          myService.getTemplate(id, $scope.getTemplateResponse, $scope.ErrorResponse);
     };
      $scope.getTemplateResponse= function (response) {
              $scope.bodyTemplate = response.Value;
      };
      $scope.ErrorResponse = function(error){
             window.location.href = "Error#?" + error;
      }
      $scope.getTemp ();
}]);
```

**myService:**

```
app.service("myService", ["ajaxService", function (ajaxService) {
      this.getTemplate= function (id, successFunction, errorFunction) {
               ajaxService.Get("http://gettempaltes.com/api/id="+id, successFunction, errorFunction);
       };
}]);
```

**ajaxService:**

```
app.service("ajaxService", ["$http", function($http) {
      this.Get= function (route, successFunction, errorFunction) {
            $http.get(route).success(function (response, status) {
                successFunction(response, status);
            }).error(function(response) {
                errorFunction(response);
            });
       };
}]);
```

Comment: which is line 27:29 pointing to??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Define $scope.ErrorResponse before you point to it. Like this

```
$scope.ErrorResponse = function(error)
{
  window.location.href = "Error#?" + error;
}

$scope.getTemp = function () 
{
  myService.getTemplate(id, $scope.getTemplateResponse, $scope.ErrorResponse);
};
```

Validate success/error fn's have been passed in before using them. Like this

```
app.service("ajaxService", ["$http", function($http) 
{
  this.Get= function (route, successFunction, errorFunction) 
  {
    $http.get(route)
      .success(function (response, status) 
      {
        if(angular.isFunction(successFunction))
        {
          successFunction(response, status);
        } 
      })
      .error(function(response) 
      {
        if(angular.isFunction(errorFunction))
        {
          errorFunction(response);
        }
      });
  };
}]);
```

Comment: it prevents to through an error in service but I have to call that error function into my controller to show the error message

Comment: @SriChatala So then you need to make sure you send it an `errorFunction`. Can you add the code that calls `myService.getCampaignEmailTemplate()` please? I'm thinking no `errorFunction` is being passed

Comment: I metioned wrong method name, I corrected my question

Comment: The error message says that "TypeError: errorFunction is not a function". Wouldn't that mean that `errorFunction` is defined, but it's just **not** a function?

Comment: @SriChatala Updated!

Comment: @austinbruch Really good question & I think you're right! I'm not too confident on what errors angular spits out for this kind of problem but that makes sense to me

Answer (score 0):

If you are using promise then change your service like this:

```
 getUserDetail: function (id) {
    var deferred = $q.defer();

    var user = $http({
        url: 'api/user/GetByUserId',
        method: "POST",
        params: { 'userId': id }
    });

    var userDetail = $http({
        url: 'api/user/GetUserDetail',
        method: "GET",
        params: { 'userId': id }
    });

    let promises = {
        info: user,
        detail: userDetail
    }

    $q.all(promises).then(function (response) {
        this.data.user = response.info.data;
        this.data.detail = response.detail.data;
        deferred.resolve(response);
    });
    return deferred.promise;
}
```

In controller:

```
ServiceName.getUserDetail(Id).then(function (data) {
    $scope.user = ServiceName.data.user;
    $scope.detail = ServiceName.data.detail;
}, function (error) {
        $scope.error = error.Message;
});
```

In this way we can queue up as much as we want, if any of them throw error, in controller error function will be called.

Comment: here I am not using promise. How importent to use $q in multiple $http request through one method? Thank you...